# How do I capture the output of a command to a file descriptor in Bourne shell?

Tags: shell, pipe, sh

The standard way to capture command output in Bourne shell is to use the `$()` syntax:

```
output=$(mycommand)
```

For commands that have a lot of output, however, this requires the shell allocate memory for the whole thing as one long string. I'd prefer to find something that does the moral equivalent of the Unix C function `popen`, to get a new file descriptor I could `read` from:

```
newfd=popen(mycommand)
while read -u $newfd LINE; do
  #process output
done
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: bash4 has a nice new feature: coproc . it would be ideal for you! too bad it is still so new

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#!bash
ls | while read X
do 
    echo  $X is a directory entry
done
```

Replace 'ls' with the command of your choice

Comment: Completely obvious once you see it. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: note the while loop is run in a subshell and so any changes it makes to variables are not passed back to the rest of the script

Comment: For instance, replace `ls` with find and echo with `printf`.